# Xcode validation fails for iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I'm trying to set up TestFlight, but can't validate my archive. Can anyone suggest a reason for this error message, or a place to look into it?

[image: An unexpected error occurred.]

Edit: I trying to create a distribution provisioning profile manually, but I keep getting hung up. Trying to add a distribution right to my account gives me another generic error message.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have this occasionally. What solves it for me is

- open Keychain Access on your mac
- delete all existing development / distributino profiles
- try again in xcode, which should fetsch (create) relevant profiles

Answer (score 0):

By refreshing your provisioning profiles in preferences - accounts. you can solved this issue .

[image]
Hope this works for you.

Comment: Sorry, I can't seem to locate anything like that. Where am I to look?

Comment: Thanks, found it. Maybe the lack of iOS Distribution  is the problem, but I can't create a profile. I edited my question.

Comment: if its solved your issue using this answer .so accept it @LanceToth